# Specifying Multiple targets for regression in TFLearn

Tags: python, regression, tflearn

How to specify multiple `target_column` in `tflearn.data_utils.load_csv` method.

According to Tflearn docs load_csv takes `target_column` as integer.

Tried passing my target_columns as a list in the load_csv method and as expected got a `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` traceback.

Any solutions for this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not how regression works. You must have only one column as a target. That's why the tensorflow API only allows **one column** to be the target of regression, specified with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

After going through TFLearn github repo ,it turns out , we cant directly use `load_csv` to specify multiple targets.

Need to read the csv file through `pandas` as dataframe and convert them to matrix using `dataframe.as_matrix()` and specify the data and label columns.

For example I had 34 columns as data set and 9 columns as targets in my csv file.

Heres what i did

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd,numpy as np

#name=input('name for run_id:')

csvfile = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')

data = csvfile[['my','data','columns']] 
label= csvfile[['target','columns']]

data=data.as_matrix()
label= label.as_matrix()
```

and as mentioned by this post https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/neural-network-for-multiple-output-regression ...just mention the no of units for the output layer and set activation as linear i.e no activation and done.

Hope this helps for others with similar situation.